# TCP override timeouts?

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcp

Short Version: I wrote .ReadTimeout = 10mins but the timeouts seem to be 30sec-1min. Can i override system/user timeouts or something?

I gave a client an app which connects to our servers. It appears that if the connection is idle for 30sec or a minute their tcp connection timeout. The client app is written .NET

Is there a way to override the timeouts? I haven't seen the problem on any of our computers. I don't want to ask the client to change their settings if i dont have to. How might i override timeouts?

I wrote NetworkStream (from TcpClient) .ReadTimeout = 10mins but obviously it is waiting much less so i guess its system timeouts? I cant override those can I?

Comment: i'll probably just have the server ping the client every X seconds

Comment: You are getting an `IOException`?

Comment: @alk: I'm not sure. I doubt the client will try connecting until a workday. I get some exception when the server tries to write to the client.

Comment: `NetworkStream.ReadTimeout` sets the timeout to elapse until a blocking `NetworkStream.Read()` will return, when waiting for data from the other side. You are getting these exceptions on the client side?

Comment: @alk: I'm not. It works fine on all machines I tested on. I have no idea what they did but i know it does work if they don't idle at all. I sent the update which has a ping command so i'll find out if that fixes the problem

Comment: The default read timeout is infinity. If the connection is being dropped it will be an intermediate router doing the dropping, or possibly the peer application.

Comment: @EJP: Yep i am getting IOExceptions "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."